# capture screen areas

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os

Is there a way to capture screen areas in the new packaged apps? Because of this Chrome bug http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68568&q=is%3Astarred&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary users cannot download their SVG files as PNGs (vector-paint.com). I know there is the chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab function but that is not accessible to packaged apps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it now in the API, although I have reported this in [a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=143866)

In the meantime, you might want to try the workarounds described in this Eric Bidelman's [HTML5Rocks post](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/streaming/screenshare/). I'm not sure if these options play well with CSP restrictions, though.